# Differentiability of a Multi-variable function $\frac{xy}{\sqrt {x^2+y^2}}$.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, problem-solving

In my book, I found a problem, asked to check the differentiability of the function $f(x,y)$ at $(0,0)$ where the function f$(x,y)$ is defined as follows

> $$
> f(x,y) =
> \begin{cases}
> \large\frac{xy}{\sqrt {x^2+y^2}},  & \text{if $x^2+y^2 \neq (0,0)$} \\
> 0, & \text{if $x^2+y^2 = (0,0)$}
> \end{cases}
> $$

Now in the book, they give a solution using alternative definition of differentiability at a point $(0,0)$
and there they have approached to a contradiction that $\frac{1}{2} = 0$

So, they proved that the function is not differentiable at all.

But when I tried to solve the problem by proving that the $f_x$ and $f_y$ exist at $(0,0)$ and the function is continuous at that point too. So basically, I prove that the given function is differentiable at that very point.

But the given solution in my book makes me confuse.
I don't understand what actually happen, Did I do something wrong if I did please make me clear? Because at the same time these two solution is not possible for this function.

And another thing can I use "sufficient condition for differentiability" for this function?

Pardon me if I did any wrong.

Thank you.

Comment: If $x^2+y^2 \neq 0$ at a point $(x,y)$ then I think $f$ is differentiable at that point by using usual methods of finding derivatives. Is your question specifically about whether it's differentiable at $(0,0)$?

Comment: In order for a function to be continuous at a point $a$ it's limit must exist and be EQUAL to it at $x=a$. Thus it is not enough for it's limit to exist, as that explicitly does not require it be defined at the point in question. So $f(x,y)$ is NOT continuous at $(0,0)$.

Comment: Oh sorry, didn't notice your $=0$ just sitting there. Thought it was a typo but you are defining it or something?

Comment: yes @coffeemath

Comment: But the given function is continous at $(0,0)$ @marshalcraft

Comment: “So basically, I prove that the given function is differentiable at that very point.” No, the conditions you have verified are not enough to guarantee differentiability. Maybe you are thinking of the criterion which says that if the *derivatives* $\partial f/\partial x$ and $\partial f/\partial y$ are continuous, then $f$ is differentiable? But that doesn't apply here.

Comment: let  $ε>0$ be arbitrary $|f(x,y) -f(0,0)| = | \frac{xy}{ \sqrt {x^2+y^2}} - 0| ≤ \frac{|x||y|}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} ≤ \frac {\sqrt{x^2+y^2}.\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} ≤ \sqrt{x^2+y^2} < ε$ @marshalcraft

Comment: By the way, if you look at the graph ([Google plot](https://www.google.se/search?site=&source=hp&q=plot+x*y%2Fsqrt(x^2%2By^2))), it should be clear that it doesn't have a tangent plane at the origin.

Comment: how can I understand where it applies and where it not? and what else do I need to prove this function differentiable? @HansLundmark

Comment: It doesn't apply, since the first partials aren't continuous at the origin. (They can't be, since that would imply that $f$ is differentiable at the origin, which it isn't.)

Comment: Please read the comments, and stop @ing me. I had not interpreted your syntax abomination at that point. Also I do not own what ever text book you own and have no idea what your asking. Note if the comments appeared differently to you than I apologize, it appears the html/js does not refresh the page?

Comment: The whole point of this problem is to illustrate that mere existence of partial derivatives doesn’t guarantee differentiability. In fact, *all* directional derivatives exist for this function. As others have already pointed out, the partial derivatives also have to be continuous.

Answer (score 3):

Let me try to show this using the very definition of differentiability. Suppose the function $f$ is differentiable at $(0,0)$. Then there is a matrix $D = (a,b)$ (the derivative of $f$ at zero) such that
$$ 0 = \lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)} \frac{|f(x,y) - f(0,0) - D \cdot (x,y)^T|}{\|(x,y) - (0,0)\|} = \lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)} \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}} \left| \frac{xy}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} -ax -by \right|. $$
Let us take two particular ways how to approach zero, say $(x,y) = (h,h)$ as $h \to 0_\pm$ (left/right). Then we have
$$ 0 = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2h^2}} \left| \frac{|h|}{\sqrt{2}} - (a+b)h \right| = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \lim_{h\to 0} \left| \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} - (a+b)\mathrm{sign}(h) \right| = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \left| \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \mp (a+b) \right|. $$
So, equalities $a+b = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ and $a+b = - \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ would have to hold **at the same time**. This is clearly a contradiction.

Comment: +1, better than my previous (erroneous) "answer".

Answer (score 0):

As in the other answer, there is no need to consider a *general* linear map. If at all $f$ is differentiable, the associated linear map must be the zero map. Let me explain why.

We have $$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\vert_{(0,0)} = 0 \quad\text{and} \quad \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\vert_{(0,0)} = 0$$
by definition of partial derivatives. Suppose $f$ is differentiable at $(0,0)$. The associated linear map $Df_{(0,0)}:\mathbb R^2\to\mathbb R$ satisfies $Df_{(0,0)}(e_1) = D_{e_1}f(0,0) = 0$ and $Df_{(0,0)}(e_2) = D_{e_2}f(0,0) = 0$. By linearity, $Df_{(0,0)}(h,k) = 0$ for all $(h,k)\in \mathbb R^2$, so $Df_{(0,0)} \equiv 0$. Now, assuming $Df_{(0,0)} \equiv 0$, it is easier to reach a contradiction - in particular by evaluating the limit $$\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)} \frac{xy}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\cdot\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} = \lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)} \frac{xy}{x^2+y^2}$$
along $y=x$, to get $\frac12\ne 0$.